# I can't upload my images into the website using android web view

Tags: android, file, webview, upload

I'm using a android webview app to access a website . In the submit section there is a button called upload image (It's only showed for users only ) .
when I try to upload the image from google chrome or my PC there is no problem but when i try to do it from the webView app and when i click the upload button nothing is happening . I know I need to get permissions and I have already got all I needed . here is my code,but I dont know what is wrong where do i miss?  I would thank you guys for your helping .

```
public class SubmitProperty extends AppCompatActivity {
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_submit);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            SubmitProperty.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://asemanhome.com/submit-property/");
}
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE){
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

}
the permissions for this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

note that I'm using the API 25 and the minversion 16 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem few days ago, this is worked for me

Add global variables

```
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;
public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
```

Add this code to `onCreate`

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Overide `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        if (requestCode == 100)
        {
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;

        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

NOTE: this will work for android 5.0 +

Comment: I have Edited my code like the one you see in first post , but still I get nothing . Is it still wrong ?

Comment: maybe the first code work for lower API's you need to check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    upload.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), upload.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                }
              });
        }
        public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override

            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }

            @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

            if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE){
                if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;

            }
       }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused a bit , where should I add this code exactly ?